# Wifi connection drops when using UART1 port on the intel edison board running android things

Tags: android-things, intel-edison

Intel Edison seems to be using the UART1 port for WIFI when running android things. As such, when I try to use the UART1, I lose the wifi connection. Has anyone had to deal with this issue and found a workaround? 
Perhaps an implementation of a software serial port similar to (Arduino Software Serial)[https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial]; any pointers on where to start to implement software serial for android things?

Comment: I have no idea about Android Things (WTF it is? Don't answer, I wouldn't like to know), though I can tell you about hardware. **UART0** (PCI BDF 00:04.1) is connected to Bluetooth which is part of Wi-Fi/BT Broadcom module, **UART1** (00:04.2) is *free running* UART, user may connect anything to it. **UART2** (00:04.3) *usually* is used as serial console, while user may or may not setup it for another specific purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Based on you feedback, my problem seems to be simply an issue with Android things which only exposes UART0 for the edison board. Perhaps they'll fix it in future versions. (Android things is just an android based OS that abstracts the hardware details for board such as edison)

Answer (score 0):

The question is, are they going to still support Edison since Intel announced that they are cancelling it.

Comment: Make another question then, but before, take a look at https://github.com/htot/meta-intel-edison/wiki